# Flash HEX onto an Arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, adafruit

The scenario: I have built a device off an Adafruit nRF52840 and I need a way to deploy firmware updates. I have delivered the device to my end user and will need to periodically send him updates.

I do not want to send him source, and he isn't technically savvy enough to compile and upload using the Arduino IDE anyway.

Searching around I see lots of suggestions to use avrdude command line to push a hex file to the board. The issue I have is my user is not going to be up for running command line... if its not a click next installer he's basically lost. I could create a BAT file and distribute a zip containing the BAT and HEX files... he double clicks the bat file and it pushes the hex to the board. This would be an acceptable solution.

My issue is the port number. Every example I am seeing of using avrdude command line includes a parameter along the lines of: "-PCOM21".

My user is not going to know what comm port the device is plugged into... and even if they knew that I dont think I can ask them to go edit the BAT file with the correct -PCOM value.

There has to be a simple solution to allow an end user to push hex firmware to Arduino boards? I am just not having much luck finding it. Is there a product that does this I should look at or could you point me to a solution?

Comment: In practice, does the port number change?

Comment: look at the `Info` section at https://github.com/dotKokott/listComPorts-csharp

Comment: turn on verbose mode in IDE and see the external command executed by the  IDE. you can use the same command

Comment: the UF2 bootloader allows drag and drop update https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF52_Arduino#bootloader

Comment: There are several [hex file loaders](https://arduboy.com/upload-games/) for the Arduino based Arduboy. Maybe the source for one of those can be modified to suit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043186/how-to-get-only-the-currently-used-serial-com-port-name-for-a-specific-usb-devic